# Why can I instantiate an abstract class without implementing an abstractmethod?

Tags: python, class, abstract-class

Trying to understand abstract classes, I created a simple model:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Publication(ABC):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    @abstractmethod
    def Description(self):
        pass

class Periodical(Publication):
    def __init__(self, title, publisher):
        super().__init__(title)
        self.publisher = publisher

class Book(Publication):
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        super().__init__(title)
        self.author = author

    def Description(self):
        print(f'Book: {self.title} ({self.author})')

class Magazine(Periodical):
    def __init__(self, title, publisher):
        super().__init__(title, publisher)

    def Description(self):
        print(f'Magazine: {self.title} ({self.publisher})')

class Newspaper(Periodical):
    def __init__(self, title, publisher):
        super().__init__(title, publisher)

    def Description(self):
        print(f'Newspaper: {self.title} ({self.publisher})')

book = Book('Thoughts', 'A. Einstein')
magazine = Magazine('Sailing', 'M. Polo')
newspaper = Newspaper('Daily Joke', 'Ms. Maisel')

book.Description()
magazine.Description()
newspaper.Description()
```

In `Publication` I define `Description()` as abstract method. If I don't implement it, e.g. in class `Newspaper`, an error is thrown: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Newspaper with abstract method Description`. That's what I intended.

But why is it possible to create `Periodical` from `Publication` without implementing `Description()`?

Comment: You cannot do that and your code here doesn't try to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not required to provide concrete implementations of abstract methods in a subclass. A subclass that does not do so simply remains an abstract base class itself.

Only when you try to *instantiate* a class is there a check for abstract methods that haven't been override. If there are, instantiation fails. You couldn't instantiate `Periodical` directly, but the class itself is just another abstract base class, with its subclasses `Book`, `Magazine`, and `Newspaper` being made concrete by implementing `Description`.

```
# Class is defined...
>>> Periodical
<class '__main__.Periodical'>

# ... but you can't instantiate it
>>> Periodical()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Periodical with abstract method Description
```